# Is there a simpler way to count the number of tokens in a string with duplicated delimiters in Kotlin?

Tags: regex, string, kotlin, tokenize, word-count

I want to count the number of tokens in a string with occasional delimiter duplicates. `String.split()` doesn't work well in this case because it doesn't deduplicate delimiters. For example:

```
val msg = "The  cat won't  stay   away  from  the chickens."
val tokens = msg.split(' ')
var count = 0
for(t in tokens)
    if(t != "") count++


tokens = ["The", "", "cat", "won't", "", "stay", "", "", "away", "", "from", "", "the", "chickens."]
tokens.size = 14
count = 8
```

I'm looking for a simpler way to get to the count of 8 in this example. Maybe there's a regex way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```kotlin
val msg = "The  cat won't  stay   away  from  the chickens."
val regex = """\S+""".toRegex()
val tokens = regex.findAll(msg).map{it.value}
println(tokens.joinToString(", "))
// => The, cat, won't, stay, away, from, the, chickens.
```

See the [Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/Uw6blj).

Here, you *extract* all non-whitespace text chunks from the given string.

This solution should be preferred as `val tokens = msg.split("""\s+""".toRegex())` (see [demo](https://ideone.com/1cI48J)) will produce extra items in case of leading/trailing whitespaces.

The splitting approach can work better if you first `trim()` the string:

```kotlin
val tokens = msg.trim().split("""\s+""".toRegex())
```

See [this Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/UO66QZ).